# In perl how can I generate all possible combinations of numbers contained in a file?

Tags: file, perl, combinations, args

I found locally the following perl code that calculates all possible combinations for chars or numbers but you need to provide them using a qw function `my @strings = [qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)];`, and I need to read these numbers (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13) from a file and pass them to the `@strings` array or pass the numbers via Perl line command arguments to the mentioned `@strings` array.

I've read all info regarding `qw()` but I didn't find a way to use it when reading a file of Perl line command arguments, so can you give some advice in order to fix this issue?.

The output provided now is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 6
1 2 3 4 7 ...
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE)];
#my $strings = [qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)];
my @strings = [qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)];

sub combine;

print "@$_\n" for combine @strings, 5;

sub combine {

  my ($list, $n) = @_;
  die "Insufficient list members" if $n > @$list;

  return map [$_], @$list if $n <= 1;

  my @comb;

  for (my $i = 0; $i+$n <= @$list; ++$i) {
    my $val  = $list->[$i];
    my @rest = @$list[$i+1..$#$list];
    push @comb, [$val, @$_] for combine \@rest, $n-1;
  }

  return @comb;
}
```

Comment: If there's one number per line check `<>` and `chomp()`, if there's one line with all numbers also check `split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this isn't right:

```perl
my @strings = [qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 )];
```

That creates an array with a single element, a reference to another array.

You want

```perl
my @strings = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 );
combine \@strings, 5;
```

or

```perl
my $strings = [qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 )];
combine $strings, 5;
```

---

`qw(...)` is equivalent to `split ' ', q(...)`, where `q(...)` is just `'...'` with a different delimiter.

This means that

```perl
my @strings = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 );
combine \@strings, 5;
```

is equivalent to

```perl
my @strings = split(' ', ' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ');
combine \@strings, 5;
```

But of course, we don't need to use single-quotes to construct the string we pass to `split`; we could use pass a string that was created from reading a file.

So, the reading-from-file equivalent of

```perl
my @strings = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 );
combine \@strings, 5;
```

would be

```perl
my $line = <>;
chomp($line);
my @strings = split(' ', $line);
combine \@strings, 5;
```

(The `chomp` isn't actually necessary because `split ' '` ignores trailing whitespace.)

Comment: ikegami, your solution is great and works with  \@strings, but I wonder why you use the backlash on it? also I tested $strings and I got an error like: Can't use string ("13") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at pgms\test2.pl line 28 is produced.TIA

Comment: Because `combine` expects a reference to an array. You can't pass arrays to subs, just scalars. We can work around that limitation by passing a reference to an array. /// I don't know what you tested, but it wasn't the code I posted. You did not assign a reference to an array to `$strings`.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code initializes an array of numbers (`@numbers`) from a file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "data.txt";
my @numbers; 

open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Cannot open $filename";

# Read each line into $line
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    # Extract each number present at $line
    while( $line =~ /(\d+)/g ) {
        # If found, add the number to @numbers
        push @numbers, $1;
    }
}

close $fh;
```

"data.txt" contents maybe something like that:

```
1 2 3
4
5
6 7 8
9
10 11
12
```

No matters if you have more than one number in each line. If fact they can be in a single row with a separator (something other than a number, like a white space)

Comment: And the corresponding call to `combine` will be `combine \@numbers, 5`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same using [Algorithm::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics):

```
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my @data = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
say join " ", @$_ for combinations( \@data, 2);
```

**Output**:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is on how to create the correct array from `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13` in a file. Maybe this should have been a comment...